# Assigning to ostream_iterators using *

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

On page 107 of Stroustrup's **The C++ Programming language (4th ed)** is an example of writing to ostream_iterators through assignment to them. A word for word copy of a subset of the example is below, but I can not compile it on VS2015 without an error and I do not understand the error message

```
std::ostream_iterator<string> oo { cout };
*oo2 = "Hello, ";        // compile error, see below
++oo2;
```

I also tried

```
*oo2 = string("Hello");  // same error
```

the beginning of the very long error message follows

```
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\iterator(317): error C2679: binary '<<': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'const std::string' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\ostream(495): note: could be 'std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>>::operator <<(std::basic_streambuf<char,std::char_traits<char>> *)'
<...more...>
```

A different version using char *'s works fine:

```
// works
std::ostream_iterator<const char *> oo5{ std::cout };  //const or no const, either works
*oo5 = "hello, ";
++oo5;
*oo5 = " world\n";
```

What is wrong with the string version?  Is this a error in the book or on my part somehow?  Thanks

**edit**
I'll also note that:

```
std::ostream_iterator<char> oo{ std::cout };
string s{ "hello, stream_iterator<char>, copy string" };
std::copy(s.begin(), s.end(), oo);
```

works

Comment: Have you included `<string>`?

Comment: This is the problem! Thanks.  I was actually using strings in several places without incident prior to the #include. I don't understand why this fixes it exactly, but it does.

Comment: The string class is used by some other parts of the standard library, so it is sometimes brought in through some implementation specific header, and this header doesn't necessarily bring everything from the `<string>` header along with it (such as the `operator<<` overload).

Answer (score -1):

Your code has a typo.  Does this work any better?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>
#include <string>
int main()
{
    std::ostream_iterator<std::string> oo2{ std::cout };
    *oo2 = "Hello, ";
    ++oo2; 
    return 0;
}
```

I get this output:

Hello,